# Read values from xml and add them into list

Tags: c#, xml

How to read the values (image1, image2, image3) from this xml file.
Its a sample and I dont know about the number of values exactly. I mean maybe the xml file has more Image Name . I want to add these images name into a list. and also I want to get ImageInterval value and set it into int variable.

```
    <Sinage DataBase>

    <Image>
        <ImageName>
            image1
        </ImageName>

        <ImageName>
            image2
        </ImageName>

        <ImageName>
            image3
        </ImageName>

        <ImageInterval>
            4
        </ImageInterval>
    </Image>
</Sinage DataBase>
```

Its my list:

```
public List<string> ImageName { get; set; }
```

I used above code for reading data but display error : `Illegal character in path`

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(global::TestGraphic.Properties.Resources.xml);

    var ImageName = doc.Descendants("ImageName");

    foreach (var image in ImageName)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(image.Value);
    }
```

Comment: this part isn't familiar to me : `global::TestGraphic.Properties.Resources.xml`

Comment: @har07 xml is the name of my xml file

Comment: Remove space from "Sinage DataBase" in tag, its invalid in XML, you can use "SinageDataBase" in tag. It will work fine.

Comment: Is `global::TestGraphic.Properties.Resources.xml` a file itself, or a path to the file? If it's a file, you should use `XDocument.Parse()` instead of `XDocument.Load()`.

Comment: you are right @MarcinJuraszek it worked. thanks. put your comment as answer plz..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `global::TestGraphic.Properties.Resources.xml` is the document content itself, not a path to a file, you should use `XDocument.Parse()` instead of `XDocument.Load()`.